# How to divide string inside html table cell depending on the length of the string

Tags: html, css, template-toolkit

I have HTML table where the content of the cell is placed using some templating engine. 
I have to make sure that the cell should have fixed width no matter how big or small the content is.

```
<td align="left" height="50px">
  <a href="#" style="padding-left:5px; display:block; line-height:18px;">
  Traditional Dhow Cruise Dinner in Dubai Creek International Ho...</a>
</td>
```

**case 1:** *If the content is small(solved).*
Then this problem can be solved by having fixed width to the cell.
**case 2:** *If the content is big.*

I should make sure all the words that can be fit inside the cell is filled and then after at the end '...' is printed.
I have tried counting the characters in the string used the template engine to place <...> after it exceeds the character count. But this does not seems to be working as HTML breaks a string depending on word. Hence sometimes even my 140 characters(limit) getting exceeded the fixed height of the cell. 
I don't mind using any templating engine to generate the desired output. Please help.

Comment: Obviously you chose a visual representation that does not fit the information it is meant to display. Don't fix the symptoms, fix the cause: Change your design.

Comment: The requirement is (as I mentioned in the case 2) if it dose not fit the visual representation then I need to put three dots(...) in the end. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Again, this is the wrong approach. Fix the design, not the information.

Comment: try this `padding-left:5px;display:block;line-height:18px;height:50px;width: 150px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;` in anchor

Comment: Thank you @Afsar. `text-overflow: ellipsis;` solved my problem :-)

Comment: @vikaskv posted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
td a{
 word-break: break-all;
 width: 150px;
 height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `text-overflow:Ellipsis` to anchor tag;

change anchor styling to:

```
padding-left:5px;display:block;line-height:18px;height:50px;‌​width: 150px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

[Info](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Clamp.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js). This library "Clamps" content inside an HTML element  by adding ellipsis. It works in all browsers.

```
var module = document.getElementById("html element");

$clamp(module, {clamp: 3}); //Clamp into three rows
```

or you can make it automatic clamping $clamp(myParagraph, {clamp: 'auto'}); or $clamp(myParagraph, {clamp: '35px'}); into a given height.

Answer (score 0):

`word-wrap: break-work`
    is another option for doing so.

`td a{
        word-wrap: break-work;
        width: 180px;
        height: auto;
    }`

`word-wrap: break-word`
    recently changed to 
    `overflow-wrap: break-word`

- will wrap words exceeding, onto the next line.
- adjusts words so that they do not break in middle.

```
word-break: break-all
```

- irrespective of continuous word or many words, breaks them at the edge of the width limit.(even within the character of same word)

But I think you need to truncate(...) the word which exceeds the td cell length, so for this you can use

```
    td a{
        white-space: nowrap;      //keep all text on one line
        overflow: hidden;         //prevent the text to shown outside border
        text-overflow: ellipsis;  //cut off text that exceeds border with an elipsis
    }
```